# Is there a way to use Huggingface pretrained tokenizer with wordpiece prefix?

Tags: huggingface-tokenizers

I'm doing a sequence labeling task with Bert. In order to align the word pieces with labels, I need the some marker to identify them so I can get an single embedding for each word by either summing or averaging.

For example I want the word `New~york` tokenized into `New ##~ ##york`, and looking at some old examples on the internet, that was what you get by using BertTokenizer before, but clearly not anymore (Says their documentation)

So when I run:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')

batch_sentences = ["hello, i'm testing this efauenufefu"]

inputs = tokenizer(batch_sentences, return_tensors="pt")

decoded = tokenizer.decode(inputs["input_ids"][0])

print(decoded)
```

and I get:

```
[CLS] hello, i'm testing this efauenufefu [SEP]
```

But the encoding clear suggesting otherwise that the nonsense at the end was indeed broken up into pieces...

```
In [4]: inputs
Out[4]: 
{'input_ids': tensor([[  101, 19082,   117,   178,   112,   182,  5193,  1142,   174,  8057,
         23404, 16205, 11470,  1358,   102]]), 'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])}
```

I also tried to use the `BertTokenizerFast`, which unlike the `BertTokenizer`, it allows you to specify wordpiece prefix:

```
tokenizer2 = BertTokenizerFast("bert-base-cased-vocab.txt", wordpieces_prefix = "##")
batch_sentences = ["hello, i'm testing this efauenufefu"]

inputs = tokenizer2(batch_sentences, return_tensors="pt")

decoded = tokenizer2.decode(inputs["input_ids"][0])

print(decoded)
```

Yet the decoder gave me exactly the same...

```
[CLS] hello, i'm testing this efauenufefu [SEP]
```

So, is there a way to use the pretrained Huggingface tokenizer with prefix, or must I train a custom tokenizer myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [tokenize](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.tokenize):

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast
t = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
t.tokenize("hello, i'm testing this efauenufefu")
```

Output:

```
['hello',
 ',',
 'i',
 "'",
 'm',
 'testing',
 'this',
 'e',
 '##fa',
 '##uen',
 '##uf',
 '##ef',
 '##u']
```

You can also get a mapping of each token to the respecting word and [other things](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#batchencoding):

```py
o = t("hello, i'm testing this efauenufefu", add_special_tokens=False, return_attention_mask=False, return_token_type_ids=False)
o.words()
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7]
```